# Alphanumeric Counter

Tags: c#

I am trying to create in C# an alphanumeric counter that creates numbers in the following way:

```
0001
0002
0003
...
9999
A000
A001
...
A999
B000
...
```

The last number would be ZZZZ. So it would 0-9 first, then A-Z after that.

I am lost on how this can be done.

Comment: Shouldn't `9999` just become `999A`?

Comment: Because this isn't true hexidecimal, you're going to have to write your own method with your custom logic.

Comment: What happens after Z999? Or does it matter that high?

Comment: Your number scheme doesn't seem to make sense.  Does it go `0, 1, 2, 3, .., 9, A, B, C, ..., X, Y, Z`?

Comment: What would the MAX value be? F999? Z999?

Comment: @Paul How do you come up with F999 and Z999 as potential "max values?"

Comment: Guys, he hasn't said anything about hexadecimal--don't assume that's what he means.

Comment: The last number would be ZZZZ.  So it would 0-9 first, then A-Z after that.

Comment: The numbering scheme isn't clear to me. You say that it's 0-9 first, then A-Z after that. But your initial example doesn't show how that's derived. Does 0009 go to 000A through 000Z before going to 0010? If A999 rolls over to B000, as your initial example suggests, then what happens after Z999? How do I get from Z999 to ZZZZ? Are you just looking for a base-36 counter?

Comment: It looks like the number scheme he is describing uses base 36, but is ordered to not use letters until it needs to, and then the fewest letters necessary.

Comment: I think the question needs clarification.  If the idea is not to use letters until necessary, then the ordering is ... strange.  Z999 would roll to AA00?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Updated to answer the clarified question.

The following code will generate the counter you describe:

0000, 0001... 9999, A000... A999, B000... Z999, ZA00... ZA99, ZB00... ZZ99, ZZA0... ZZZ9, ZZZA... ZZZZ

```
public const int MAX_VALUE = 38885;

public static IEnumerable<string> CustomCounter()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_VALUE; ++i)
        yield return Format(i);
}

public static string Format(int i)
{
    if (i < 0)
        throw new Exception("Negative values not supported.");
    if (i > MAX_VALUE)
        throw new Exception("Greater than MAX_VALUE");

    return String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}",
                         FormatDigit(CalculateDigit(1000, ref i)),
                         FormatDigit(CalculateDigit(100, ref i)),
                         FormatDigit(CalculateDigit(10, ref i)),
                         FormatDigit(i));
}

private static int CalculateDigit(int m, ref int i)
{
    var r = i / m;
    i = i % m;
    if (r > 35)
    {
        i += (r - 35) * m;
        r = 35;
    }
    return r;
}

private static char FormatDigit(int d)
{
    return (char)(d < 10 ? '0' + d : 'A' + d - 10);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Update: After your comment I think there is a mistake in your question. What you probably want is just a simple base 36 counter. Here's one way you could implement it:

```
string base36Characters = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

string toBase36(int x, int digits)
{
    char[] result = new char[digits];
    for (int i = digits - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        result[i] = base36Characters[x % 36];
        x /= 36;
    }
    return new string(result);
}

IEnumerable<string> base36Counter()
{
    for (int n = 0; n < 36 * 36 * 36 * 36; ++n)
    {
        yield return toBase36(n, 4);
    }
}

void Run()
{
    foreach (string s in base36Counter())
        Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

---

Original answer: I would probably implement it using yield:

```
IEnumerable<string> magicCounter()
{
    // 0000, 0001, ..., 9999
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        yield return i.ToString("0000");
    }

    // A000, A001, ..., Z999
    for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; ++c)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        {
            yield return c + i.ToString("000");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `i.ToString( "0000" )` or `"000"` would also work for padding.

Comment: @user54064: If the last "number" should be 'ZZZZ' then I think your question has an error in it.