# Endless (almost) alphanumeric counter

Tags: c#

Trying to build upon the answers in this thread [ [Alphanumeric Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007308/alphanumeric-counter) ] to build an endless (for any int) alphanumeric counter without padding.

I want to create a counter that starts at 0 and counts something like this.

0,1,2...Y,Z,10,11,12...1Y,1Z,20,21...ZY,ZZ,100,101...ZZZ,1000,1001 .. infinity (overflow)....

The purpose of the counter is to create short URLS from my database `INT` id's. I want to input the id of the row and get a base 36 value from it that i can use as the url.

I've made a few attempts but they all seem to end up wrong. I'm getting stuck on how I can test when I should increase the number of characters. i.e. go from Z to 10 or from ZZ to 100.

Comment: Requesting an "endless" counter and later realizing that 32-bits is a little shorter is unkind to those making an effort to help.

Comment: I apologize, it was not my intent. I will however probably rewrite my model and code because of Jon Skeet's answer in order for it to truly be unlimited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (string x in EndlessBase64Sequence())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }

    private static char NextBase36Char(char c)
    {
        if ((c >= '0' && c <= '8') ||
            (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'))
        {
            return (char) (c + 1);
        }
        if (c == '9')
        {
            return 'A';
        }
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> EndlessBase64Sequence()
    {
        char[] chars = { '0' };

        while (true)
        {
            yield return new string(chars);

            // Move to the next one...
            bool done = false;
            for (int position = chars.Length - 1; position >= 0; position--)
            {
                if (chars[position] == 'Z')
                {
                    chars[position] = '0';
                }
                else
                {
                    done = true;
                    chars[position] = NextBase36Char(chars[position]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Need to expand?
            if (!done)
            {
                chars = new char[chars.Length + 1];
                chars[0] = '1';
                for (int i = 1; i < chars.Length; i++)
                {
                    chars[i] = '0';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this is probably more than i need.
The purpose of the counter is to convert my database INT ids to alphanumeric urls. I tried to clarify my question a bit to show this. But now that you have shown me this I might have to remove my int column and use this as my ID column so I can truly have endless rows in my database =)

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10619/Base-36-type-for-NET-C) "Base 36 type for .NET" project seems to look like it would plug right into what you need.

Comment: That's not endless. It has a maximum value of `long.MaxValue`. We can do better :) Admittedly this is *practically* infinite as `long.MaxValue` is pretty darned big, but...

Comment: Then again. Is anything infinite in computing?

Comment: In practice, no it's not infinite, but there is certainly a difference between "this number can be up to 64 bits long" and "this number can be as large as you've got the memory to store".

Comment: I'll leave this up here for others to find, but I think @JonSkeet's answer nails what the OP needs. I was too lazy to fire up VS and code that up :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up using for now.

Its not infinite but I changed my MVC3 models ID's to long (MVC3 does not support ulong) which has a max value of 9223372036854775807. I doubt my system will have more rows than that..

```
    private const string base36Characters = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    public static string toBase36(long x)
    {
        String alpha ="";
        while(x>0){
            alpha = base36Characters[(int) (x % 36)] + alpha;
            x /= 36;
        }
        return alpha.ToLower();
    }
```

Tested it for numbers up to zzzzz, then my laptop stops working...

Comment: That is not endless it goes up to `int.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: Very true. But then I will also have a problem of my ids in the databases being ints. I might have been a little unclear in my question but the purpose for me is "I want to input the id of the row and get a base 36 value from it that i can use as the url.". So I dont need a truly endless solution but a more endless solution than the previous thread was providing.

Comment: Change the first line of the while loop to `alpha = base36Characters[(int)(x % 36)] + alpha;` and you can have it pass in [any data type that supports `%` and `/`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) instead of a int, (which btw gets you to 0 through 3W5E11264SGSF for ulong.MaxValue)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Updated my answer and MVC3 model after your comment ;)

Comment: The uniary operator (int) has a [higher precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) than the Multiplicative operator, you must put the 2nd set of parentsis in, your edit is equivalent to `((int)x) % 36` so any number bigger than x.MaxValue will be truncated before it does the divide.