# How to find out next character alphabetically till ZZ

Tags: c#

I am using following code for finding the next alphabet.

```
    string rev = "Value";
char C1 = char.Parse(rev);
c1++;
```

But the value for rev string does not end at Z, it goes up to AZ which is last value. (like excel columns just for reference).
So, above code will not work for values like AA, AB and it will not increment it.
I am not sure how we can find next value if I get rev value as "AA". Can someone guide.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3007567/10753968) help you? It's alphanumeric so not exactly what you're asking, but seems like the logic applies

Comment: Can you define the rules more clearly? Give us some inputs and expected outputs. "AA" -> "BA"? "ZA" -> "AZA"? etc.

Comment: Can you give a example with input and expected output?

Comment: @sinatr the inputs could be anything see the below examples. eg 1. Input c the output I'm expecting is D. But when my input is Z the output should be AA, this is like an excel column name. and when input is AB out put should be AC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a straightforward, if perhaps slightly verbose or expensive way of doing this.

It expects the input to be well-formed, and will throw an exception if it doesn't contain just the letters A-Z.

```
public static string Increment(string input)
{
    List<char> chars = input.ToList();
    
    // Loop over the characters in the string, backwards
    for (int i = chars.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (chars[i] < 'A' || chars[i] > 'Z')
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Input must contain only A-Z", nameof(input));
        }
        
        // Increment this character
        chars[i]++;
        
        if (chars[i] > 'Z')
        {
            // Oops, we overflowed past Z. Set it back to A, and ...
            chars[i] = 'A';
            
            // ... if this is the first character in the string, add a 'A' preceeding it
            if (i == 0)
            {
                chars.Add('A');
            }
            // ... otherwise we'll continue looping, and increment the next character on
            // the next loop iteration
        }
        else
        {
            // If we didn't overflow, we're done. Stop looping.
            break;  
        }
    }
    
    return string.Concat(chars);
}
```

Test cases:

```
A -> B
B -> C
Z -> AA
AA -> AB
AB -> AC
AZ -> BA
BC -> BD
ZZ -> AAA
```

See it on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BoQwpL).

Comment: The given sample `Value` also includes small letters

Comment: @fubo Indeed, which is why I stated that upfront, and included the test cases. I'll delete/edit if and when we get some clarification: I find sometimes the easiest way to get that feedback is to put something in front of the asker, and let them say if/why it's wrong!

Comment: @canton7 the above code you provided worked for me. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @sayyad If this solved your question, please consider marking it as the accepting answer (and upvoting it)